# Terminating bash script in case else statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a script. In the beginning of the script, I want it to check for internet connectivity and then continue, else the script should stops with message "please check your internet". I am new in bash programming, that why I am not sure that whether "if-then-else" should be used here or "while". Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if
    ping -c 1 google.com >& /dev/null
then
    echo "INTERNET IS WORKING..."
else
echo "PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET!"
fi
cd $HOME/download
pwd
```

In this script, in case the "if" statement fails, and the  script runs the "else" statement, I want this script to stop, instead of going further to "cd $HOME/download" and "pwd".

How can I do this in this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

if ping -c 1 google.com >& /dev/null
then
    echo "INTERNET IS WORKING..."
else
    echo "PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET!" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cd "$HOME/download" || exit 2

pwd
```

I also changed

```
echo "PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET!"
```

to print error message to standard error and

```
cd $HOME/download
```

to

```
cd "$HOME/download" || exit 2
```

to exit if `cd` failed, for example because `"$HOME/download"` does not exist. There are no more warnings reported by [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: Or just `if ! ping ...; then exit 1; fi`

Comment: Arkadiusz Drabczyk: It worked perfectly... Thanks a lot man :-)
Kusalananda: Interesting, I will definitely check it.

Comment: @Kusalananda: from what I understood, OP always wants to print something on the screen so it would be `if ! ping ...; then echo INTERNET IS NOT WORKING >&2; exit 1; fi` but at least `else` wouldn't be needed

Comment: Yes, I always want "Some Message" to be printed on screen. I have a further query in this regard: If I want to use 'exit' again then should I go with exit 3, exit 4 and so on?

Comment: @SalmanAhmed: it's up to you, everything non-zero means failure.  If there are a lot
of places in which your script could exit with failure incrementing
exit status might get daunting very quickly.  In that case `exit 1`
plus a clear error message would be enough. If there are only a few
places in which your script could exit, I'd increment exit status with
each non-success `exit` so that caller immediately knows what's
happened just by looking at `$?`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk That was my point. I kept it short, because comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @SalmanAhmed: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [what should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)